# perform nslookup from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I'm writing a powershell to exact the ip from a server name, which need me to embed the nslookup code into my powershell

how can I do the intergrating work?

Can any body help me?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity “http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp“
$server_status = "PROD"
$list=$web.Lists[”DNS_Status”]
$items = $list.items 
Foreach($item in $items){
    $item_name = $item["Server_name"]  #need to get the ip by this name

    /*nslook up*/
     $item_name.update()

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you install the [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) module, it comes with a cmdlet `Resolve-Host` which handles name lookups.

Absent that, this one-liner will do the job

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.msn.com")
```

You can also pass in an IP address - but the results will be different.

See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/26/647318.aspx & http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/210.aspx

Comment: Your one-liner is the simplest way to do it on Windows 7.

Comment: While I thought the same thing, `[System.Net.DNS]` and `nslookup` use totally different methodologies to query DNS records. 1. `[System.Net.DNS]` uses your local cache first,  `nslookup` does not. 2. `[System.Net.DNS` will query for an A record if a PTR lookup fails and then respond with the "reverse". `[System.Net.DNS]` is NOT a good diagnostics replacement for `nslookup`.

Answer (score 7):

PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 8 and higher comes with a `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet that will get this information:

```
(Resolve-DnsName $server_name)[0].IpAddress
```

Comment: v3 does, v2 does not.  Also - you accidentally called it `Resolve-DnsClient` in your first line :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that when I wrote it but somehow that didn't make it down to my fingertips. :-)  And yeah, DnsClient is the module named.  Fixed.

Comment: Can you clarify in your answer that the DnsClient module is available only in Windows 8? [Richard Siddaway](http://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/powershell-v3-installed-modules/) says it "can’t be made available on Windows 7 because the underlying WMI classes aren’t available".

Comment: 'Resolve-DnsName' on Technet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781(v=wps.620).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
Resolve-DnsName monServer | ? { # make selection here } | % { $_.IPAdress }  | select-object -first 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Here is a far better method for nslookup

# HOWTO ensure an nslookup results no errors but still gives the original names and column separations
$day = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd #<-- HOWTO set the day variable for today
$ErrorActionPreference = ‘SilentlyContinue’ #<-- HOWTO turn off error messages
$WarningActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' #<-- HOWTO turn off warning messages
$servers = Get-Content .\input\servers.txt
Foreach ($server in $servers){
$result = Resolve-DnsName $server -Server $env:LOGONSERVER.Remove(0,2) -Type ALL #<-- NSLOOKUP using your logon server
write-host ($server+","+$result.Name+","+$result.IPAddress) #<-- HOWTO Write two variables separated by a comma
}
$ErrorActionPreference = ‘SilentlyContinue’ #HOWTO turn on error messages
$WarningActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' #HOWTO turn on warning messages
```