# Getting IP address while using Test-Connection

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to add the IP address to this script, it would be perfect if I could get this to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.
The input files has host names, and I like to get the IP address into the csv please.

```
$servers = Get-content "servers.txt"
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s);"IP" = what to put here? }
    if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $status["Results"] = "Down" 
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus

}
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `-Quiet` would suppress the information you are looking for. Remove the quiet and instead capture the results in a variable you can then query for both success and the ipaddress.

```
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s)}
$result = Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($result)
{ 
    $status.Results = "Up"
    $status.IP =  ($result.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
} 
else 
{ 
    $status.Results = "Down" 
    $status.IP = "N/A"
}
```

I am unsure if this logic would produce misleading information but I am playing around with it just in case.

If you have already made the switch to IPv6 then you might be more interested in `($result.IPV6Address).IPAddressToString`

Comment: also `($result.IPV6Address).IPAddressToString` works too if your servers are switched over to the new IP configuration :)

Comment: Would I be able to add a NSLOOKUP to this for the ones that failed?

Comment: @Steve Yes. You can just run nslookup direct from PowerShell but you would have to parse the output which is not ideal. You also look at the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394552/perform-nslookup-from-powershell) and run that inside your else block.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Matt, you helped me work through my issue.

I found that I wasn't able to use (.) in the new variables. Could be my own misunderstanding. I post this that it may help others with my same issue.

Based on your answer plus an example of how I had to adjust.

```
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s)}
$result = Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($result)
{ 
    $StatusResult =  "Up"
    $statusIP =  ($result.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
}
```

Comment: Uh, what? I only get an echo of the script... no response...